# lxml throwing xslt parse error - not able to template match any other than root

Tags: python, xml, xslt, lxml

I'm using python/lxml to translate source xml to a target xml format. I keep getting a XLSTParseError when I try to match template to any other elements than root ('/') but cannot figure out what is wrong - pretty sure its namespace related though...The content i am trying to access from source xml is contained in the  elements. Any idea how to fix or how to get lxml to output more detailed error msg?

Source xml has declaration:

```html
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <dataroot generated="2016-10-24T09:16:37" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="BOLIG_XML.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:od="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:officedata">
 <BOLIG_XML>...</BOLIG_XML>
 <BOLIG_XML>...</BOLIG_XML>
```

```
...
```

Target xml has declaration:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <BoligListe xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="urn:oio:lbf:1.0.0">
     <BoligStruktur>...</BoligStruktur>
     <BoligStruktur>...</BoligStruktur>
        ...
```

XSLT currently looks like this:

```html
 xslt_tree = etree.XML('''\
        <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
        <xsl:template match="/">
         <BoligListe xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="urn:oio:lbf:1.0.0">
            <xsl:template match="BOLIG_XML">
                    <BoligStruktur>hello world</BoligStruktur>
                </xsl:template>
            </BoligListe>  
        </xsl:template>
        </xsl:stylesheet>'''
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Each `xsl:template` element needs to be a top level element of the stylesheet root element, you can't nest templates as you seem to try to do in your XSLT code. You then use `xsl:apply-templates` to process child elements with a matching template so I guess you want

```
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <BoligListe xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="urn:oio:lbf:1.0.0">
           <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </BoligListe>  
    </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template match="BOLIG_XML">
                <BoligStruktur>hello world</BoligStruktur>
            </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```